# Hyperledger Fabric: Encrypt ledger data in a single channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a multi-org fabric network where all the orgs are on a single channel.

I understand that using the composer acl file we can hide data from the users based on their roles and other conditions.

However, the data will be visible when we get into the peer container of any org and issue a `peer channel fetch`.

So, my question is, is there a way to encrypt this ledger data when the orgs shares the same channel? [Here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/Fabric-FAQ.html), they mention about encrypting the data. Is there any example/reference that can get me started on that one?

Currently, I'm not planning to use different channels between different orgs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are few ways to protect the ledger data. Like your mentioned in your question, [Hyperledger Fabric FAQ](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/Fabric-FAQ.html), official gives five different ways to help us to achieve security and access control.

In the newest version of [Fabric](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric), which is tagged v1.2.0, provided a new definition called *private data*. I prefer to use this method to build my access control in my apps. 
Since I am using [Fabric Node SDK](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-private-data.html) to deploy and control the fabric network, and it provides a convenient way for me to embed it into the exists projects.

Using the configuration file to define who can persist data, how many peers the data is distributed to, how many peers are required to disseminate the private data, and how long the private data is persisted in the private database. All the upgrade that you need to do is adding some parameters when install and instantiate, modifying some function to invoke the private data, writing some codes to handle the configuration file and users control.

It gives some examples for us to use this new feature:

[Chaincode example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/marbles02_private/go/marbles_chaincode_private.go)

[SDK example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.2/test/integration/e2e/private-data.js)

Comment: I'm using Composer for exposing the fabric to the client. Correct me if I'm wrong but only Fabric 1.1 supports it.

Comment: @MrudavShukla It's true that fabric 1.2 cannot thoroughly support composer for now, check this issue to get more detail. https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4238